# Javascript uncaught error

Tags: javascript

I have this code below. Sorry for its view, but i formatted it with an online formatter.

Why do i get this error, when i click the submit btn?
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined" - Line 55, thats the line, after i declare the variables.

```
$("#KerdesForm").on("submit", function(b) {
    b.preventDefault();
    var c, d, e, f, g, h, mennyiseg, cim = [];
    c = $("#kerdes_nev").val(), 
    d = $("#kerdes_email").val(), 
    e = $("#kerdes_tel").val(), 
    f = $("#kerdes_uzenet").val(), 
    cim = $("#cim").val(), 
    mennyiseg = $("#mennyiseg").val(),
    g = $("#KerdesItemID").val(), "" == $.trim(c) && h.push("Nem adta meg a nev\xe9t."), "" == $.trim(d) && h.push("Nem adta meg az e-mail c\xedm\xe9t."), "" != d && 0 == a(d) && h.push("Elk\xe9pzelhet\u0151, hogy hib\xe1san adta meg az e-mail c\xedm\xe9t."), "" == $.trim(e) && h.push("Nem adta meg a telefonsz\xe1m\xe1t."), "" == $.trim(f) && h.push("Nem \xedrt semmilyen k\xe9rd\xe9st vagy \xfczenetet."), "" == $.trim(g) && h.push("Hi\xe1nyzik a term\xe9k ID."), "" != g && ($.isNumeric(g) || h.push("A term\xe9k ID nem sz\xe1m t\xedpus\xfa.")), 0 == h.length ? $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        cache: !1,
        data: {
            nev: c,
            email: d,
            tel: e,
            kerdes: f,
            termek: g,
            mennyiseg: mennyiseg,
            cim: cim
        },
        url: "files/new_ajanlatkeres.php",
        success: function(a) {
            $.trim(a), $("#KerdesForm")[0].reset(), $("#kerdesButton").hide(), $("#kerdesButton").prop("disabled", !0), $("#AjanlatResult").fadeIn("fast").html('<div class="javascript_success">' + a + "</div>"), setTimeout(function() {
                location.reload()
            }, 1e4)
        }
    }) : $("#AjanlatResult").fadeIn("fast").html('<div class="javascript_rror_div">' + h.join("<br/>") + "</div>")

})
```

Comment: Well, `.push` is a method of arrays. You can't call push on arbitrary variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's init your `h` variable as array

```
h = []
```

Answer (score 0):

### h is undefined

The error here is that you have not defined `h`

In this line only `cim` is an array:
`var c, d, e, f, g, h, mennyiseg, cim = [];`

you must give it the value of an array

like:

`var h = []`

but I think your code is a little complex, making it very difficult to debug. Please take a look at [the single responsibility principal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)

You should also stop using single letter variables because they tel you nothing about the variable or what it holds.